# GoogleApiClient is stuck in connecting state, no error reported by debug

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-play-services

So as the title suggests, for some reason the google API Client is stuck in connecting state with no error in the debug info.  I have waited up to 5 mins for a response.

Here is the code to track my current location.

```
public class myLocation implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback,
        LocationListener
{


    public static final String TAG = myLocation.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private final static int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;

    //global variables for information passed on from parent class
    public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = null;
    private Context mParentBase;
    private Activity mParentActivity;
    private PendingIntent mParentIntent;

    private LocationRequest requestLocation;

    public Location mMyLocation;

    /**
     * Constructor For this class
     */
    public myLocation(Context Base, Activity activitiyBase, PendingIntent intent) {
        mParentBase = Base;
        mParentActivity = activitiyBase;
        mParentIntent = intent;
        initialLocationService();
    }

    /**
     *  Initialize the Location Service and API Client
     */

    public void initialLocationService(){
         mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mParentBase)
             .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
             .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
             .addApi(LocationServices.API)
             .build();

         requestLocation = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10*1000)
            .setFastestInterval(1*1000);

         Log.d(TAG, "Initialization Location Service");
     }

    public void connect()
    {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection Requested");
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mParentIntent);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        Log.d(TAG, "OnConnected");

        if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ==
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mParentBase, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)))

        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission Was Granted" );
            mMyLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

            if (mMyLocation == null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, requestLocation, mParentIntent);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, mMyLocation.toString());
            }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mParentActivity, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission Was Requested" );
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ==
                            (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mParentBase, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)))

                    {
                        mMyLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

                        if (mMyLocation == null) {
                            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, requestLocation, mParentIntent);
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, mMyLocation.toString());
                        }
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mParentActivity, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services suspended. Please Reconnect.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Failed");

        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(mParentActivity, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }

    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mMyLocation = location;
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
    }
}
```

Here is the code that calls the my location object:

```
public class selectRouteAndTransportMethod extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent mIntent;
    PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
    myLocation mCurrentLocation;
    public static final String TAG = selectRouteAndTransportMethod.class.getSimpleName();
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_route_and_transport_method);

        mIntent = new Intent(this, selectRouteAndTransportMethod.class);
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mIntent, 0);
        mCurrentLocation = new myLocation(this, this, mPendingIntent);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.

        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Log.d(TAG, "On Start");

        while (mCurrentLocation.mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Google ApiClient Not Instantiated");
        }
        mCurrentLocation.connect();

        while (true) {
            boolean connecting = mCurrentLocation.mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting();
            boolean registered = mCurrentLocation.mGoogleApiClient.isConnectionCallbacksRegistered(mCurrentLocation);
            //ConnectionResult connectionResult = mCurrentLocation.mGoogleApiClient.getConnectionResult(LocationServices.API);

            if (connecting == TRUE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Connecting");
            }

            if (registered == TRUE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "registered");
            }

              //  Log.d(TAG, connectionResult.toString());

            if (mCurrentLocation.mMyLocation != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output from the debug log.

```
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
```

Comment: Did you replace the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

I think this has something to do with your `while(true) {}` loop. Try changing that to an `if-statement` instead. What's happening is you've just put yourself in an infinite loop predicament. You can see the proof of infinite loop on your debug log.

Comment: Thank you so much, but what thing that puzzles me, is i thought, the connection the API client was asynchronous and what not a part of the main thread, was my assumption wrong?